# Receiving socket information from netfilter NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING hook function in linux kernel

Tags: android, linux, kernel, hook, netfilter

I wrote a netfilter hook function for incoming packets in linux kernel. Is there a way to get the receiving socket information from the hook function. The code is

```
register() {
        hk.hook = hookfunction;
        hk.hooknum = NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING;
        hk.pf = PF_INET;
        hk.priority = NF_IP_PRI_LAST;
}

static unsigned int hookfunction (void *priv,struct sk_buff,const struct nf_hook_state *state) {
        if (skb->sk) {
                printk("%d", skb->sk->sk_mark);
        }
}
```

Lets assume I have a udp socket open at port 15000 and a udp packet arrives at port 15000. In the above written hook function how can I access the struct sock of the udp socket opened at port 15000. With the above code, the control doesnot pass the if(skb->sk) condition as if skb->sk is null. Can you please suggest me a way to get the struct sock of the socket or should I have to put the hook in some other position like NF_INET_LOCAL_IN,. I am also confused about the difference between NF_INET_XX_XX and NF_IP_XX_XX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel uses `__inet_lookup_skb()` internally to get sk from skb, which calls `skb_steal_sock()` first to check if **skb->sk** is **NULL**, if that is the case, it then calls `__inet_lookup()` to lookup sk.

However you might need to tweak the kernel a little bit because `__inet_lookup_skb` symbol is not exported and can't be called directly.

Some references from kernel source:
[1](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.6/source/include/net/inet_hashtables.h#L337) [2](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.6/source/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L1590) [3](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.6/source/net/dccp/ipv4.c#L803)

Regarding `NF_INET_XX` if you are talking about `NF_IP_PRE_ROUTING` and `NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING` I believe `NF_IP_PRE_ROUTING` is obsolete in recent kernel, as far as I know 4.4 has replaced it with `NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Will go through the kernel. To test I put a hook in NF_INET_LOCAL_IN. I noticed that I was able to get the sock struct of connected sockets (like tcp sockets) but was not able to get the sock struct of unconnected sockets (like UDP sockets).